# Hyper V Environment report PowerShell script to web browser

Tags: c#, powershell, hyper-v

All - Good Morning,

A colleague of mine has setup a power-shell script on a local server which generates a Hyper V environment report for our virtual cluster and at present sends it via email as a HTML file. This all looks pretty and is great (sample of the PS command below)

```
.\Get-HyperVReport.ps1 -Cluster Hvcluster1 -SendMail $true -SMTPServer 0.0.0.0 -MailFrom sender@hyperv.com -MailTo recepient1@hyperv.com,recepient2@hyperv.com
```

My question is how can I get the output of this file hosted on one of our web servers so that we can monitor the report at frequent intervals?

I am still pretty new to C# so forgive me if my question isn't worded all that well.

Comment: This doesn't, exactly, have anything to do with `c#`, `powershell`, or `hyper-v`. Putting an html file onto a web server is just a question of getting the file into a directory served by a web server. That's not really something anyone here can help you with.

Comment: Your script needs to send the HTML content to a file that's in a location served by a web server on your network. But without seeing the code in your script, no one here can say *how* to do that - nor do we have any details about where your script runs, where you have web servers, or how you can get content to them.

Comment: When you say you want to monitor the report more frequently, you would also need to run the powershell script as frequently or on demand, right? If yes, in addition to what alroc said, you will need schedule the script to be run at regular intervals and change the script to upload the generated report to the web server.